# How can I dynamically label Gmail messages based on a field in the header?

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, gmail-labels

I would like to label each incoming message based on the `List-ID` header.  I want this label to be generated dynamically as needed because of the volume of lists to which I am subscribed as well as the number of Github projects I follow which also populate the same `List-ID` header with the source repository.

For example, an ideal filter would match

```
'from:(notifications@github.com)'
```

and then apply the label

```
'GH/Repos/${Header:List-ID}'
```

Comment: This needs to be done via a custom Google Apps Script using the Gmail API

Comment: Yeah, it simply can't. Unbelievable... https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/Workspace-Q-A/Filtering-words-in-email-headers/m-p/511648/highlight/true#M9313

Comment: Actually, GMail understand the List-ID header: `list:(125163.projectname.group.gitlab.com)` for gitlab. So.. they even have syntax for header matching, but has artificially limited it to the "standard" (subset of?) headers?